# Как быть если соединение с Интернет было разорвано. Повторить выполнения команды python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, try-catch

Если нету интернет соединения, в случаи ошибки как снова открыть и потом продолжить выполнения дальнейшего кода. Проверка если команда выполнилась, то продолжить программу, если ошибка (проблемы с интернетом, разорван), повторить команду через 10 секунд (100 раз)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, re, time,random,datetime,os,errno,traceback; 
while 1:  
    #...другой код
    try:
        driver.get('https://account.mail.ru/login'`)
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
        traceback.print_exc()
#... другой код
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File ...in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="Login"]"}
>     (Session info: headless chrome=78.0.3904.70)

Answer (score 1):

Пример того, как можно бесконечно ждать соединения:

```
while 1:  
    try:
        driver.get('https://account.mail.ru/login'`)
        break # Выйти из цикла в случае успеха
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
        traceback.print_exc()
        time.sleep(10) # Спать 10 сек, если exception
```

Если нужно ограничиться конкретным количеством попыток, то можно использовать цикл FOR:

```
attempts = 5
for i in range(attempts):
    try:
        driver.get('https://account.mail.ru/login'`)
        break # Выйти из цикла в случае успеха
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
        traceback.print_exc()
        time.sleep(10) # Спать 10 сек, если exception
```